# iteration trough the nested array with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, quasar-framework

I have a question regarding v-for. I have an object like below:
[image]

and in dev console it look likes that:
[image]

now my question is, how can I iterate through the each array and also the array inside the main array with v-for. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693839/iterating-through-nested-objects-with-v-for) but it didn't work.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    items: [{
        messageSettings: [{
        userOne: '1',
        userTwo: '2'
      }],
      profile: [{
        freelancerAbout: 'about1',
        freelancerName: 'name1'
      }],
      messages: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'message1'
      }]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item">
      <p v-for="msgSetting in item.messageSettings" :key="msgSetting">
        <span>UserOne: {{ msgSetting.userOne }}</span><br>
        <span>UserTwo: {{ msgSetting.userTwo }}</span>
      </p>
      <p v-for="profile in item.profile" :key="profile">
        <span>freelancerName: {{ profile.freelancerAbout }}</span><br>
        <span>freelancerName: {{ profile.freelancerName }}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is difference between our array, as you can see each item inside my array has an index number,for example to get the data of profile I need to do this:```profile[0].freelancerName``` that's why when I try your solution I am getting errors.

Comment: No need to use index while using `v-for` as it is iterating over the index items only.

Comment: Best practice is to use id in `:key` but it just a warning of vue. 